# Wordpress: how to use get_categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a ajax call to a php file which uses get_categories(). But it always says "Call to undefined function get_categories()" How can I make it to work? What should be included?

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['slug'])) {
    echo get_categories(array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat'))[0]['slur'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax php file put below line in the top.

```
include_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```